# Rails using uniq_by method with nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a CollectionProxy of nested records:

```
@saved_videos = Video.all.is_saved
@sentences_to_extract = @saved_videos.map(&:sentences)
```

Each video has many sentences, and each sentence has one keyword, eg

```
[
  [Video.id: 1, 
    sentences:
      [Sentence.id: 1, keyword: 'hello'],
      [Sentence.id: 2, keyword: 'friend']
    ],
  [Video.id: 2, 
    sentences:
      [Sentence.id: 3, keyword: 'hello'],
      [Sentence.id: 4, keyword: 'mum']
    ]
]
```

When I try:

```
@sentences_to_extract.uniq_by(&:keyword)
```

it returns

```
undefined method `uniq_by' for #<Array:0x000001031f7968>
```

What is the best way to return a single collection of sentences with unique keywords, or in more general terms, to get a selection of nested records by a particular unique attribute?

Comment: First do `@sentences_to_extract = @saved_videos.flat_map(&:sentences)`, and then `@sentences_to_extract.uniq { |a| a.first[:keyword] }` is what you want..

Comment: `Array#uniq` exist, but not `uniq_by`.. **Note:** `[Sentence.id: 1, keyword: 'hello']` is basically `[{Sentence.id: 1, keyword: 'hello'}]`

Comment: What's your Rails or ActiveRecord version? Do you just need the `keyword`?

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @ArupRakshit this is solved: I need to *flatten* the mapped arrays by one level, achieved in a one liner with [*flat_map*](http://martinfowler.com/articles/collection-pipeline/flat-map.html).

Working code:

```
Video.all
     .is_saved.flat_map(&:sentences)
     .uniq { |s| s.keyword.downcase }
```